# Extracting the meaningful information from the text column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a table with the two columns. I have to extract the meaningful information out of it from the Notes column. i.e. I need to extract the date in one column and the information after the date in one column and then ID

```
Notes, ID
Movie Date 05-28-2018 Passed, 1010
MTD loan slip dated 8-10-14 the Issued, 1111
Max over date 10-2-15 and repaired, 11232
```

output-

```
Notes                               ID      Date        Status
Movie Date 05-28-2018 Passed        1010    5/28/2018   Passed
loan slip dated 8-10-14 Issued      1111    8/10/2014   Issued
Max over date 10-2-15 and repaired  11232   10/2/2015   repaired
```

Here is my code-

```
df = pd.read_sql('select * from <table>', engine)
searchfor = [' dated', ' date', ' Date', ' Dated']
df2 = df[df['Notes'] .str.contains('|'.join(searchfor), na = False)]
..................
```

Appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: In the above post, "output" as my desired output. Please let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would some some loops for that.

---

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

searchforstatus = [' Passed', ' Issued', ' repaired']

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in searchforstatus:
        if c in row['Notes']:
            df.loc[idx, 'Status'] = c
```

---

**Result**

```
                                    Notes     ID     Status
0            Movie Date 05-28-2018 Passed   1010     Passed
1  MTD loan slip dated 8-10-14 the Issued   1111     Issued
2      Max over date 10-2-15 and repaired  11232   repaired
```

---

The data that I used can be found here:
https://files.fm/u/npaceyd6#_

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's throwing an error - argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. Would you mind to send me the complete code.

Comment: Hello. The code works fine for me. I updated a link for the data that I used. I have them in a .csv file and I updated my answer to show how I load them

Answer (score 0):

Regex after getting the rows from iterrows() can also extract information, if there can be many possibilities

```
  s = 'Movie Date 05-28-2018 Passed'
  p = re.search(r'Dated?\s(\d+-\d+-\d+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)',s)
```

p.group(1) will have the date value and p.group(2) will have the value 'Passed'. Hope this helps..

Comment: for `s = 'MTD loan slip dated 8-10-14 the Issued'` this does not work for me

Comment: Yes. That may be because of the way the pattern is devised. It is looking for a 'D' in the word date but in this case it starts with a small 'd'. The pattern can be changed like                                
   re.search(r'D?d?ated?\s(\d+-\d+-\d+)\s([a-zA-Z]+.*)',s) and it is matching with small or upper case Date and also captures rest of the string after the date. Hope I am clear..